# System Argument Exception "Parameter is not valid" Image Data Type using C#

Tags: c#, image, ado.net

I am trying to read Image file from `Data Type image` format in SQL SERVER.

**C#**

```
private void SalesMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = "my connection string";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string fileName = ""; 
        byte[] data; // 

        using (conn)
        {
            using (cmd)
            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"select CAST(compressedimg AS VARBINARY(MAX)) ReceiptCompressed from tb1 where id = 684489";
            
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        fileName = "InvoiceName";
                        data = (byte[])reader["compressedimg"];

                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            SaveData(fileName, data);
                        }
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();

            }
        }
    }

protected bool SaveData(string FileName, byte[] Data)
    {
        using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Data))) //parameter is not valid
        {
            image.Save("MyImage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        return true;

        
    }
```

I tried other links of stackoverflow as well. it doesn't work. same error.

I tried without converting database field to VARBINARY(MAX) as well. same result

Comment: Write the bytes to file and first see if its a valid image, then use a tool to see what sort of image it is, if it's an svg or some funky formst all bets are off

Comment: Additionally saving images to databases is traditionally a contentious issue anyway

Comment: @TheGeneral I disagreee about "saving images to databases is traditionally a contentious issue", saving files to database is totally fine, but there are scenarios where does not make sense at all (for example applications that retrieve very often those files and write them to disk)

Comment: @TheGeneral i directly write to file. Yes, it's invalid image. It's a traditional software, that storing image on `image` datatype. what tool to see the image. please

Comment: @Cleptus contentious meaning doing so is likely to cause controversy one way or another. The irony is, just mentioning that is does, caused controversy... :)

Comment: @TheGeneral Thought it meant it was problematic, it does indeed cause controversy :-D

Comment: If it's not a valid image, why are you trying to create an `Image` from it?

Comment: @Charlieface that records start with `0x5A00`, this data stored in image datatype of sql server, It's stored by our Traditional software, and also I can view this data only on that same traditional software. what I need is, i need to figure it out what type of file and extract the file and store it as pdf

Comment: OK so just save it using `FileStream` or `File.WriteAllBytes`. I just don't get why you are bringing `Image.FromStream` into it, that is intended for bitmap images. The fact that you are storing it in an `image` column in the database (which is deprecated in favour of `varbinary`) is **entirely irrelevant**. It's just a file, not a bitmap image.